# Delete PDF files only from folder using Applescript on MAC

Tags: pdf, applescript, delete-file

I need to delete the PDF files only from a folder on a network drive. There are other file types in the folder I can not touch. I am assuming I have to choose or identify the PF files first and then move them to the trash or delete them.

What I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Kathlene:Desktop:ABC123_JOB"
    set destFolder to "Server/JOBS/TRANSFER_TRASH/"
    set thePDFs to every file of theFolder whose name extension is "pdf"
    move thePDFs to destFolder
end tell
```

What I get for an error:

> error "Can’t get every file of \"Macintosh
>   HD:Users:Kathlene:Desktop:ABC123_JOB:\"." number -1728 from every file
>   of "Macintosh HD:Users:Kathlene:Desktop:ABC123_JOB"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to delete (files of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Kathlene:Desktop:ABC123_JOB" whose name extension is "pdf")
```